Has Russia imported any weapons from Iran except "Shahed" drones?

Iran is on its way to replacing Russia as a leading arms exporter


(...) together with the reports that Iran sold more than two thousand drones to Russia alone, (...)

Has Russia imported any weapons from Iran except "Shahed-136" drones?

hard to be sure https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57007/did-iran-send-400-ballistic-missiles-to-russia

https://www.bbc.com/russian/articles/ce31rvqxex7o
https://www.wsj.com/world/u-s-tells-allies-iran-has-sent-ballistic-missiles-to-russia-9558f4c4
https://edition.cnn.com/2024/09/06/politics/iran-transfers-ballistic-missiles-russia/index.html
https://www.thetimes.com/uk/defence/article/ballistic-clmpm3d7m
https://ru.euronews.com/2024/09/08/iran-missiles-to-russia-ru

There's going to be a lot of secrecy around any weapons shipments, so any answer is probably going to have to rely on western intelligence (or journalism based on intelligence sources) or some other source that may not be 100% trustworthy. Whether you accept such sources is up to you.

Allegedly, yes, the EU wants to sanction them for selling short range ballistic missiles to Russia

Brussels says it has received evidence that Tehran has supplied ballistic missiles to Russia for use in Ukraine. Meanwhile, Russia says it has captured a village as forces inch towards Pokrovsk. Follow DW for the latest.

See also Ballistic missiles to Russia: US, Europe sanction Iran
Now, of course, one can choose to believe Iranian denials but:

Iran does sell the Shaheds to Russia
Iran is allegedly getting SU-35s at some point.
Iran likes missiles (probably a left over from the Iran-Iraq city-busting exchanges) and has given plenty to Hezbullah for example.

Artillery shells are also alleged (CNN March 2024):

Iran sent at least 300,000 artillery shells last year — “probably more than that,” the official said

